# invoke command on remote machine is not working using powershell

Tags: powershell

I ran the below commands on my machine to download data from one server to another server using the invoke command

```
Enable-PSRemoting -force 

Enter-PSSession Server1

invoke-command -computername Server1 -credential:'dom\jack' {c:\temp.ps1 -server serverX -id 4231e429-d238-4e32-a1bb-0ee812cd3124 -download $true}
```

ERROR is: Failed: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

but when i run the above command on my machine as

`c:\temp.ps1 -server serverX -id 4231e429-d238-4e32-a1bb-0ee812cd3124 -download $true`

it works as expected.

Is there something i am missing when i execute it remotely....please help me.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this good References:
http://www.ravichaganti.com/blog/?p=1108
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff700227.aspx

> It might be something to do with the TrustedHosts or Authentication
>   setting of a client. You can set it like this:WinRM set
>   winrm/config/client @{TrustedHosts="*"}

Read more about this here: 
http://blogs.dirteam.com/blogs/sanderberkouwer/archive/2008/02/23/remotely-managing-your-server-core-using-winrm-and-winrs.aspx

I use

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -WindowStyle Hidden -NoLogo
```

I use this code:

```
try
{

    Invoke-Command -credential $testCred -computer $ServerName -scriptblock { 
        param([String]$scriptDeploy, [String]$destino)  &"$scriptDeploy" 'parametro1' $destino
        $ScriptBlockOutput = $Error
    } -ArgumentList $RutaRemotaParaScriptDeInstalacion, "$dirRemotoDestino" 

    "`r`n`r`nOK para script de despliegue"
    exit 0;

}
catch
{
    "`r`n`r`nError en script de despliegue"
    "`r`nError in " + $_.InvocationInfo.ScriptName + " at line: " + $_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber + ", offset: " + $_.InvocationInfo.OffsetInLine + ".";

    exit -1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable remoting on the remote machine. You also need to make sure the firewall/anti virus does not block the remoting ports. These are port 5985 for http, or port 5986 for https.

If both machines on the same domain it's fairly easy to get working. If the machines are on different domains however then it's more complex. There's a registry setting that needs to be changed on the remote server, and you need to pass credentials. Have a read here for [more info](http://www.thecodeking.co.uk/2011/02/winrm-with-mixed-domain-environments.html). There is of course ssl which can also be enabled, but that's another story.

Comment: i followed the New-Itemproperty -name LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy -path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System -propertyType DWord -value 1 commands also, but no luck...i found the same error as it was showing first time

Comment: So are the ports open? Does `telnet servername 5985` connect? Is the trusted hosts configured on the remote host? Start with a simple remoting call like `-scriptblock { get-process }`, and get that working first.

Comment: ports are open i can see "WinRM already is set up for remote management on this machine" when i run winrm quickconfig                                           $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "xyz@J123" -AsPlainText -force  
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("dom\jack",$securePassword)  
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server1 -ScriptBlock {c:\temp.ps1 -server serverX -id 4231e429-d238-4e32-a1bb-0ee812cd3124 -download $true} -Credential $credential 
but no luck. could you please give some more info on how to run telnet or trusted host configured?

Comment: `Telnet` can be used to test if a port is open/reachable, it can be installed in windows features. To add a trusted host refer to `Trusted hosts` in the article I linked to. Can you try a `get-process` as I suggested? Does this work? Have you set the execution policy on the remote machine?

Comment: Yes i ran get-process as "Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server1 -ScriptBlock {Get-Process} -Credential $credential" and it lists all the process. i have also set the execution policy on the remote machine as "remotesigned". today i used different server but on that server also same behaviour Error: "Failed: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"

Comment: That means the access denied is when running the temp.ps1 script. Can you login as that user and run the script? What does the script do? Does it require elevation?

Comment: As i communicated earlier this problem is comming only when i remotly invoked the command, otherwise it is working perfect, its functionality is to retrieve date from windows update. elevation is not required but still i tried in elevated mode also.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in your script.

You should not be executing Enter-PSSession before the Invoke-Command, because the Invoke-Command itself sets up the PSSession.
Use only this:

```
Invoke-command -computername Server1 -credential:'dom\jack' {c:\temp.ps1 -server serverX -id 4231e429-d238-4e32-a1bb-0ee812cd3124 -download $true}
```

... Without the Enter-PSSession