# How to make an exe running on the different machine using powershell, invoke command is not helping out?

Tags: powershell

I have two machines 'A' and 'B'. I want to execute an exe which is on 'B' from machine 'A' using powershell commmand as follows:

```
invoke-command -computername B -scriptblock {start-process "D:\folder\sample.exe"}
```

Now, it simply do not make sample.exe up on machine 'B'.
Both machines are able to access the items of each other and the platform is windows. So, please help how can i have it up running on other machine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [invoke command on remote machine is not working using powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508137/invoke-command-on-remote-machine-is-not-working-using-powershell)

Comment: What kind of application is `sample.exe`?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @alroc this application actually visualizing some data by using opengl and is developed in vs2012 and i have alreday kept its all dependencies on the other machine.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers i don't get any error .

Comment: So how do you know it's not working? Please describe the problem in more detail.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers as on the machine'B' i don't see any exe up and running, even i have checked the taskmgr also in that no process as 'sample.exe' is shown as running.

Comment: Is Remoting enabled on B? Does `D:\folder\sample.exe` exist on B? Can you run the programm manually? Does the eventlog on either host say anything about this? Do you get more information when you run `Invoke-Command` and/or `Start-Process` with the parameter `-Verbose` or `-Debug`? "Doesn't work" is an insufficient problem description. We don't sit in front of your computer(s), so you need to give us something to work with.

Comment: AFAIK you can't start a GUI process on a machine via PowerShell Remoting (which is what you're doing here). Give `psexec` from the Sysinternals utilities a look.

Comment: @alorc yes you got the point .. i used psexec and i got success in remote execution...thakyou.