# Install Bluetooth Driver on Remote HP Laptop with Powershell

Tags: powershell, driver, remote-access, invoke-command

I am looking to install bluetooth driver to 30 HP Elitebook 840 G3 laptops, and I am looking to do it with Powershell.

I can do this locally:

```
Start-Process "C:\\installer\\bluetooth.sp74472.exe" -argumentlist "/s" -wait
```

But I can't seem do this to a remote machine:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -scriptblock {Start-Process "C:\\installer\\bluetooth.sp74472.exe" -argumentlist "/s" -wait}
```

The process just won't start at all on the remote machine... What am I missing?

Comment: The installer works without user input silent? As I remember, HPs bt-drivers are a bit special... I owuld guess, that it might be this. Do you see any process started? Else try `Invoke-Cimmethod -computername $computername -classname win32_process -name create -arguments "C:\installer\bluetooth.sp74472.exe /S"`

Comment: thank you restless1987, i've tried a range of arguments, also without any at all, still no respond, and I don't see any process started. I will try your suggested script and  come back with the result...

Comment: Hi @restless1987 , I've tried your code: `Invoke-Cimmethod -computername id-l-00511 -classname win32_process -methodname create -arguments @{commandline = bluetooth.sp74472.exe'; currentdirectory="c:\installer"}` , it returns a table with return value 9.

Comment: It returns a table with Process Id {empty}, return value {9}, PSComputerName {computername}. Still, nothing happens in the remote computer...

Comment: This return value says `path not found` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389388(v=vs.85).aspx). When you run the `.exe` locally, it creates a folder at `c:\swsetup` or something like that. There should be a dir for you bluetooth drivers. You could try this files to run - maybe the `exe` does not support this installation method. The HP-Drivers don't do it consistenly.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing exactly what you are seeing, my best guess is that the laptop has not been configured to allow remote powershell.

For more info: [How to run powershell commands on remote computers](https://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/)

On the HP machine you need to open an elevated Powershell session and enter

```
Enable-PSRemoting -Force
```

Also make sure your execution policy has been configured.

This person had a similar issue: [invoke command on remote machine is not working using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508137/invoke-command-on-remote-machine-is-not-working-using-powershell)

Comment: Thank you @Christopher for your comment. The client's laptop has already configured to accept remote powershell and have proper executuin policy. The posted code was part of a larger script which install Skype, Silverlight, and other. It is only in this part where it suppose to install bluetooth driver that the computer stops responding.. It doesn't give me any error message, it just stalls for hours... :/